# Heroku chat app works, but how to integrate it?

Tags: node.js, heroku, github, express, socket.io

So I have a working chat application, based off of Socket.IO's own example: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

Now the first problem I had was modifying this for it to work with Express 4.0 and Jade, which my website uses. This was not too challenging, and the updated code that works with Express 4.0 is at : https://github.com/coolbnjmn/heroku-socket.io

You can see it in action at http://salty-escarpment-7398.herokuapp.com/chat
With this in mind, I then tried to get this chat to work with my current website, and this is where I ran into troubles. The changes I had to make to make it just work locally were as follows:

First, I had to change the line (in index.js):

```
 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

to

```
 var port = 3000;
```

because I was having a EADDRINUSE error. I had no other servers running in the node application, but it was still giving me this. This is the first issue that I do not know how to resolve, because to get my site working with heroku again (it also uses heroku, like my sample app) will need to use process.env.PORT instead of a statically assigned port number.

Second, I had to change the line (in public/main.js):

```
 var socket = io.connect();
```

to

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

because I was having an error stating

```
 "http://localhost:5000/socket.io/1/?t=1398462814085 404 (Not Found) " error.
```

Third and last: I had to change the line (in views/chat.jade):

```
 script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

to

```
 script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

because I was having an error stating

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined 
 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Now with these changes, the app works just fine locally, on

```
 "http://localhost:3000".
```

But I'm trying to get this back onto the Cedar stack of Heroku. What do I need to do for the original 3 lines of code to work in my app. Is it a dependency issue? I did a npm prune and reinstalled just what I thought I needed, but maybe I still have too many? I'm opening a database connection, could that have something to do with the EADDRINUSE?

I'm pretty stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've hard coded port 3000, but Heroku assigns a variable port, so your changes will not work.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that. What I'm asking is how to go from having a hard coded port to having a variable port, like what heroku does